# form submit hook handler not getting called in drupal

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

I have `Drupal 7` site. It has custom module named say `myproducts`. This module has following hook

```
function myproducts_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

if(isset($form_id) && $form_id=='product_node_form')
{
   $form['#submit'][] = 'myform_form_submit';
}

}


function myform_form_submit(){
 echo 'test submit handler'; exit();
 }
```

#### But `myform_form_submit` is not getting called.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The submit for the node form is attached to a specific button, so something like this should work:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'myform_form_submit';
```

Comment: do I need to replace #submit with my submit button id ??

Comment: Nope, the structure is already there it should just be a matter of adding another function name to that array

Comment: Nopes, still not getting called

Comment: Be sure to use `dpm($form);` within the form_alter hook to find out exactly where the submit element is located within the $form array. It may not necessarily be in `$form['actions']`. (You need to install the Devel module to run `dpm();`)